# How to fix the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" error for a solution deployed in production?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a VueJS(+quasar) frontend that is using two backend developed by myself.

The backend are not in the same domain.

The backend's domain are :

- https://user-backend.net (manage user and application rights)
- https://data-backend.net (contains all my business data)

And the frontend's domain is :

- https://myapp.net

I use Axios as an API reader, both backend gives api's endpoint.

So I had the AXIOS cors problem when I was on dev mode (localhost with different ports) So to get around the problem I ran my browser without the web safeties, as it was only development.

However, today I put the application in production and I have this error again.

So I looked for several solutions on the Internet and each time I was offered the same step to work around.

So I followed one of them and here is what I put:
`axios.js`

```
export default boot(async ({ app }) => {
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] =
    "*";
});
```

But now, here it is, for a development environment I think it's not a problem but now that I'm in production, how can I fix this problem?

I'm really bothered with these CORS POLICY and I'd like to fix this problem with the most optimized way for production.

Here is the console log error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://user-backend.net/tokens' from origin 'https://myapp.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is CORS  error not SOP, so this is not related to the front-end, backed must set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : * // or your domain for more security`

Comment: what do you mean by "CORS error not SOP" ?

Comment: CORS is the error from backend and server doesn't let a domain to access the source, while SOP is related to the browser, browser doesn't let request to be excuted to protect user from XSS or etc  , read more here https://medium.com/datamindedbe/cors-and-the-sop-explained-f59de3a5078

Comment: I see. But when I disable web security on Chrome, I can run my application without any problem? 

I'm not implying that it's SOP, but by simply disabling the safeties on Chrome, it works.

What I want is to run it without disabling those safeties

Comment: I had the same issue and if you try it in Postman , it will response ok, but with chrome is not allowed to do it, I fixed it by setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *  in my backend